# Php não atribui valor na $_SESSION

Tags: php

Esse sistema de cadastro, tenho um botão para deletar o produto no BD´

```
<form action="remove-produto.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$produto['id']?>">
    <button class="btn btn-danger">remover</button>
</form>
```

quando ele vai ao remove produto ele executa isto:

```
 $id = $_POST['id'];
 removeProduto($conexao, $id);
 $_SESSION["success"] = "Produto removido com sucesso";
 header("location:produto-lista.php");
 die();
```

Ele deleta normalmente e retorna o perfeitamente ao produto-lista.php
que há esse trecho em espera

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION["success"])) { ?>
    <p class="alert-success"><?= $_SESSION["success"]?></p>
<?php  } ?>
```

Já tentei adicionar o `SESSION_START()`, que ja se encontra em outra pagina, a de login. Vi com o `var_dump` e fala que `$_SESSION["success"]` é null.

> PHP Version 5.6.15
>
> Xampp 3.2.2

A session está habilitada e variáveis globais também.

Comment: Em toda pagina que ocorrer sessão, você precisa utilizar `session_start()` como primeira declaração. Tente adiciona-lo em ambas as paginas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes de você atribuir isso:

```
$_SESSION["success"] = "Produto removido com sucesso";
```

Coloque um `session_start()` e quando for imprimir também, pois você tem que utilizar o `session_start()` em todas as páginas onde você precisa usar sessão.

Comment: Não sabia disso, achava que só precisava em apenas 1 lugar, obrigado!!! Solucionou 100%

Answer (score 1):

A ordem correta para gravar na sessão em PHP é:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["success"] = "Produto removido com sucesso";
session_write_close();
```

Sendo que o ultimo comando serve para gravar e fechar a session.

Caso queira ler a sessão, considere:

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION["success"];
```